# android Inapp Billing: remove ads

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In my android app, im showing some small ad banners at the bottom of the screen in some activities. I now want to give the user the opportunity to remove this ads via in-app billing.

What is a good way to implement that?

As the ads are showing up immediatly after the start of some activities, querying googles service for purchased items every time i am showing an ad seems to be bad as it takes some time to connect to the service.
I thought about querying googles service once while in a splash screen, using a boolean in my application context singelton to store the information if adfree is purchased. In the activities `onCreate`, I then check if boolean `isPremium` is true. If this is the case, im setting the visibility of the adview to false `findViewById(R.id.adview).setVisibility(false)`.

Is this safe?
Im not sure if the ApplicationManager can kill my ApplicationContext where the variable is stored without killing all activities.

Comment: I also want to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Boolean` and set the variable to `null`. Then only query once if it is `null` (lazy init). If your app gets killed it will start out as `null` and you will simply query again. Also probably a better idea to actually remove the `AdViews` otherwise they will continue to issue ad requests and you will get very low CTR.

Comment: That sounds good. As I need the Data immediatly after startup, ill use a combination of that with SharedPreferences. At each check of the BillingService, ill also update a sharedPref boolean to fall back to if boolean is null but i need to know if premium is purchased.
As the Pref updates frequently, this should also be save from user manipulation.
And i will make the AdViews be removed completly. Thanks for that hint (I thought they stop upgrading if not visible, but didnt check that)

Comment: @nikolay-elenkov Do you happen to know which countries that I manually need to report and pay VAT tax for on In-app billing with Google? I have read that Japan needs manually reporting. Anyone else? I would be happy If you could read/answer my Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506835/android-in-app-billing-vat-tax

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to remove ads after purchase

```
if (!bp.isPurchased("prime")  {
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }else if(bp.isPurchased("prime") ){
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);

        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

I am using https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 library